# How can I install the app for iPhone to iOS Simulator on the ARM/M1 powered Macs?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I want to install my app that is built for my iPhone device to Xcode's iOS Simulator on the new ARM/M1。but there was a problem when I launch the App on  Xcode's iOS Simulator。Here is the system log I captured

```
错误        14:44:29.621556+0800        SpringBoard        Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.
默认        14:44:29.629920+0800        runningboardd        <OSLaunchdJob | handle=EAC5325C-2547-42F2-A874-B938385158E1>: submitAndStart succeeded, state=2
错误        14:44:29.630074+0800        runningboardd        Launchd didnt have information for pid 32748, reason: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=113 "Unknown error: 113"
错误        14:44:29.630111+0800        runningboardd        Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 32748: (os/kern) failure (0x5)
错误        14:44:29.630897+0800        SpringBoard        Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x136899180; application<com.obtenir.TestM1>:<invalid>> with error: <NSError: 0x600000fddfe0; domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain; code: 5; reason: "Launched process exited during launch.">
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem？

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the App Store on an M1 mac.

At the bottom left where you see your name, click on it.

Your account page will appear.

Under the word 'Account' are two buttons, 'Mac Apps', 'iPhone and iPad Apps'

Click on 'iPhone and iPad Apps'

Now you will see a list of apps on your iPhone and some that are not but perhaps you once had.
Click on the 'open' button on the app you want to run and the app will start.

Note this is not the simulator but the REAL app. To debug this app you need a debugger.

Use XCode's debugger
https://developer.apple.com/support/debugging/

Here is an introduction to the debugger
https://raygun.com/blog/debug-ios/

Here is a more complete reference
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_application_debugging.htm